# What is a level 4 carcinogen?

Tags: safety

My friend spilt a "level 4 carcinogen" on their lap.  What is it and how dangerous is it?

They had washed if off after.

Comment: Do you know the actual chemical? I'm not sure how many different classification schemes exist, I think the US and Europe use different ones at least.

Comment: @mad pyridine might be it.

Comment: Did they tell you any other details? For example, what was the compound, was it in a solid form or a liquid/solution, how long was it in contact before being removed?? There are many types of carcinogens which affect us through different mechanisms (e.g. inhalation, absorption through skin, radiation, etc.) so this will determine the level of risk your friend has been exposed to. Also, any idea what classification system the "level 4" is from. In all of the classification systems I have looked at, the danger decreases with level (level 1 being most carcinogenic).

Answer (score 3):

There are [several different ways to rate carcinogens](http://toxipedia.org/display/toxipedia/Hazard+Rankings#HazardRankings-CancerInformation).  According to [its MSDS](http://www.mathesongas.com/pdfs/msds/MAT19990.pdf), Pyridine belongs to **Group 3, A3:  Known to cause cancer in animals, inadequate evidence in humans**.

If it was just contact with the skin, your friend should wash it off with soap and water immediately for 15 minutes *(this is again from the MSDS)*.  Short term exposure can cause *"irritation (possibly severe), allergic reactions, sensitivity to light."*

So, if any irritation occurs, it is probably not serious, but **I would recommend seeing a doctor anyways.**  I doubt there is anything to worry about, but cancer is not something to mess around with.